# Scroll down with JavaScript or JQuery when click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to fix it by myself looking for it here, and I found a lot of answers, but I just can't figure it out how to implement that code into my page.

I know that I might have things that shouldn't be like that, but im learning and right know what I want to solve is that.

The only thing I wanna do is to scroll down to the class ".separador" when I click the button.

this is the HTML, CSS and JQuery code:

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $('html, body, article').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".separador").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
*, html{
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
}

body{
 background-image: url("fotos/principal.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 7%;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(112,112,112,0.65) 0%, rgba(112,112,112,0) 52%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(112,112,112,0.65) 0%,rgba(112,112,112,0) 52%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(112,112,112,0.65) 0%,rgba(112,112,112,0) 52%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6707070', endColorstr='#00707070',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
 copy
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
}

ul li{
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;

}

ul li a:link{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;

}

ul li a:visited{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover{
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:active{
 color: white;
}



article{
 float: left;
 position: relative; left: 20%; top: 200px;
}

#MBOLD{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
}

#MTHIN{
 font-size:45px;
}

article div button.btn {
  background: #808080;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10;
  -moz-border-radius: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

article div button.btn:hover {
  background: #666666;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #000000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #000000);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #000000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #000000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666666, #000000);
  text-decoration: none;
}

article div.separador{
 width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>VR EXPERIENCE</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
 <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
 <style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab');
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.xhtml">Inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="Mercado.xhtml">Mercado</a></li>
   <li><a href="Estadisticas.xhtml">Estadísticas</a></li>
   <li><a href="Conócenos.xhtml">Conócenos</a></li>
  </ul>
 </header>
 <nav></nav>
 <article>
  <div id="MBOLD">VR Experience</div>
  <div id="MTHIN">Supera los límites</div>

  <div>
   <button type="button" onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('second'))" class="btn">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
  <div class="separador">
   
  </div>
 </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `smoothScroll()`..? Did you mean to make `$(".btn").click(function() { });` into `smoothScroll()`? Other then that, have you tried to enter in info into `.seperador`? It scrolls fine on Chrome.

Comment: Separating the fact of your missing `smoothScroll` function, the scroll animation is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you missed updates method names. I've taken the liberty of replacing your `$(".btn").click(function() {});` into `smoothScroll()`. I also removed the parameters passed into `smoothScroll()` on the html `<button>`

I also replaced `$('html, body, article').animate({});` with `$('html').animate({});` because you only need to specify the top level element.

```js
var smoothScroll = function() {
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".separador").offset().top // You can add padding by adding/subtracting from this value
    }, 2000);
};
```

```css
*, html{
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
}

body{
 background-image: url("fotos/principal.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 7%;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(112,112,112,0.65) 0%, rgba(112,112,112,0) 52%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(112,112,112,0.65) 0%,rgba(112,112,112,0) 52%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(112,112,112,0.65) 0%,rgba(112,112,112,0) 52%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6707070', endColorstr='#00707070',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
 copy
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
}

ul li{
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;

}

ul li a:link{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;

}

ul li a:visited{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover{
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:active{
 color: white;
}



article{
 float: left;
 position: relative; left: 20%; top: 200px;
}

#MBOLD{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
}

#MTHIN{
 font-size:45px;
}

article div button.btn {
  background: #808080;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #808080, #4a4a4a);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10;
  -moz-border-radius: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

article div button.btn:hover {
  background: #666666;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #000000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #000000);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #000000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #000000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666666, #000000);
  text-decoration: none;
}

article div.separador{
 width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>VR EXPERIENCE</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
 <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
 <style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab');
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.xhtml">Inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="Mercado.xhtml">Mercado</a></li>
   <li><a href="Estadisticas.xhtml">Estadísticas</a></li>
   <li><a href="Conócenos.xhtml">Conócenos</a></li>
  </ul>
 </header>
 <nav></nav>
 <article>
  <div id="MBOLD">VR Experience</div>
  <div id="MTHIN">Supera los límites</div>

  <div>
   <button type="button" onclick="smoothScroll()" class="btn">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
  <div class="separador">
   deténgase aquí (Stop here)
  </div>
 </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the  element you are setting a onclick event for a undefined function, remove it so it looks like below.

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

And update your .btn click function to

```
 $(".btn").click(function() {
 $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".separador").offset().top
     }, 2000);
 });
```